# JSON Schema: How to extend with more properties?

Tags: jsonschema

Let's say I have a simple JSON like:

```
"values": {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 0,
    "D": 0,
    "E": 0,
}
```

A, B, C are part of the basic schema T1 while D,E are part of an extending schema T2. Therefore the schema T1 has 3 properties while T2 has 5 properties. I would like to avoid write A,B,C twice, in both schemas.

Is there anyway in JSON Schema to extend the list of properties?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on how to use references? http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html Are you looking for other details not mentioned there? =]

Comment: Yes, I have. And they are great for sub part that are similar. If I had A and B that had the same sub objects. But I need a schema T1 with properties A,B,C and a second schema T2 with properties D,E. And then I need a way to make a schema allowing all the properties from T1 and T2: A,B,C,D,E. I need the union of two schemas. I am not sure what I say makes sense.

Comment: In which case, you need to use `allOf`. Have you seen that keyword? If not, I'll share details in an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have seen. But reading from it seems that I won't work for expanding a schema with another since both schemas needs to pass. If both schemas have additionalProperties: false, it is not possible for them to both be valid on the same input. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split out your schemas in a way which reflects extending objects, where some of your schemas have `additionalProperties: false`, you need to hoist up the `additionalProperties: false`.

You can use a definition in each schema to define the object without additionalProperties: false, then the root schema allOf reference the definition with additionalProperties: true. Then in the other schemas, you can reference the previous schema's definition.

Unfortunately, it's a limitation with draft-7. In draft-8, it is possible to do what you want with a new keyword, but it's not published yet.

Comment: Thanks :) In the meantime, if we need, we may go around the issue with preprocessing the schemas for including sub-parts.

Comment: In case you're still looking to make this better, as of JSON Schema 2019-09, you can use the `unevaluatedProperties` keyword, which can "see through" applicator keywords.